# D3 Dot Matrix Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, matrix, charts

looking for a code example of a dot matrix chart, created with the latest version of D3.  Essentially trying to achieve something like the attached image.

[image: dot matrix chart]

Comment: Welcome. Please show what you got so far and where your problems lie.

Comment: What is your data model?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is already implemented by [Arpit Narechania](https://github.com/arpitnarechania). You can use his [javascript library](https://arpitnarechania.github.io/d3-dotmatrix/) to render Dot Martix Charts out of the box or [look at his code snippet to write your own](http://bl.ocks.org/arpitnarechania/71740f18ae4ef6052ebe8e7ced9cff1b).

Using the library is as simple as can be:

```
<script src="/path/to/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/dist/DotMatrix.css"></script>
<script src="/path/to/dist/DotMatrix.js"></script>
<div id="DotMatrix"></div>

...

var chartOptions = {
    dot_radius: 5,
    no_of_circles_in_a_row: 40,
    dot_padding_left: 5,
    dot_padding_right: 5,
    dot_padding_top: 5,
    dot_padding_bottom: 5
};
DotMatrixChart(yourDataset, chartOptions);
```